# jackson not maintaining case of object serialized

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson

When I serialize my bean with `jackson`, the `json` response i view in Fiddler is lower case and the case is not maintained to what I have in my bean

This is with `jackson` in `spring mvc`

this is my bean

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyCmd {

    @XmlElement
    private List<myType> objMyType;

    @XmlTransient
    public List<myType> getobjMyType(){
        return objMyType;
    }
    public void setCMSTypes(List<myType> objMyType){
        this.objMyType = objMyType;
    }
}
```

If i view the `json` in Fiddler the object root is `objmytype` rather then `objMytype` and the other elements are lower case as well.

How do I get the json to maintain the same case as that of the bean?

My controller that handles the request

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"dosomething.json"})
public void getDoSomething(HttpServletRequest req, Model model){
    MyObjCmd cmd = new MyObjCmd();
    //populate cmd
    model.addAttribute(cmd);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't fiddler messing up? Try sending the request from a different HTTP client and checking the body of the response directly.

Comment: I checked in in chrome as well, under developer tools -> network and viewed the response. same as fiddler

Comment: Show us your handler method that returns an object of tpye `MyCmd` and your MVC configuration.

Comment: What happens if you respect the JavaBean naming conventions, and name your getter method `getObjMyType()`? And while you're at it, you should also rename the class `myType` to `MyType` (and choose much better names)